# unable to parse json string in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this below function in which i am calling another function `"uploadContentVersion"` which is a request POST. This also includes a callback which i am capturing in the below function .

The issue which i am facing is this line `"console.log(data)"` is giving me result like this

```
{"id":"11111111111111","success":true,"errors":[]}
```

But when i am trying to print `console.log(data.id)` i am getting undefined.Not sure where i am doing wrong.

```js
const createFileFromJSON = async() => {
    if (fs.existsSync('./templates/officetemplate.docx')) {
      const templateFile = fs.readFileSync('./templates/officetemplate.docx');
      //console.log(templateFile.toString('utf8'))
      var doc = await handler.process(templateFile, data);
      // 3. save output
      fs.writeFileSync('./templates/' + data.accPlanId + '.docx', doc);
      uploadContentVersion(sfdc_token.access_token, sfdc_token.instance_url, data.accPlanId, function(data) {

        var conn = new sf.Connection({});
        conn.initialize({
          instanceUrl: sfdc_token.instance_url,
          accessToken: sfdc_token.access_token
        });
        console.log(data) -- > {
          "id": "11111111111111",
          "success": true,
          "errors": []
        }
        console.log(data.id) -- > undefined
        attachFileToRecord(conn, data)
      })
      // console.log(contentversionres)
    } else {
      console.log('Template is not present..')
    }



    var uploadContentVersion = function(token, instUrl, fname, callback) {

      var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': some url,
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "VersionData": fs.readFileSync(`./templates/${fname}.docx`).toString('base64')
        })

      };
      request(options, function(error, response) {
        if (response.statusCode === 201) {
          callback(response.body);
        }
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
      });
    }
```

Comment: First thing I'd check was whether the JSON was what you expected it to be. Without that, the error could be in it's generation, or in your request.

Comment: {"id":"11111111111111","success":true,"errors":[]} -- > This is correct JSON which i am receving.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the issue. I just passed `JSON.parse(response.body).id` from request and it solved the issue

Comment: The reason being that `data` was of type string and therefore `data.id` resultet in undefined. As soon as you use `JSON.parse` it is converted to an object that javascript can "read".

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be that you are recieving `data` as a *string*, not as an Object. In your answer, you responded saying that adding [`JSON.parse()` (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) worked. This is because JavaScript interpreters have no way of knowing that you want it treated as an object, so the JSON.parse function was made to fix that. There is also the opposite, JSON.stringify.